# Every ideal of polynomial ring over field has smallest field of definition

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, commutative-algebra, field-theory, ideals

Let $I \subset K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ be an ideal. Subfield $K' \subset K$ is called a field of definition of $I$ if $I$ has a generating set in $K'[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$. I want to show that there exists a field of definition $K_0$ of $I$ which is contained in every other field of definition.

See $K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/I$ as a $K$-vector space and find a set $M$ of monic monomials whose images comprise a basis. Every other monic monomial $m$ can be uniquely expressed as a linear combination(with coefficients in $K$) of $M$s modulo $I$. Let $\sum_i c_i m_i + m \in I$ be such an expression. Suppose that $K' \subset K$ is a field of definition. Then $\sum_i c_i m_i + m = \sum_k d_k p_k$ for some $p_k \in K'[x_1, \ldots, x_n], d_k \in K, 1 \le k \le m$. Let $m = m'_1, \ldots, m'_l$ be the monic monomials outside $M$ used in the $p_k$s, and let $C$ be a matrix over $K'$ such that $C_{ij} = $ the coefficient of $m'_i$ in $p_j$.

Since
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1
\\
\vdots \\
0
\end{bmatrix} = C\begin{bmatrix}
d_1
\\
\vdots \\
d_k
\end{bmatrix}$$

has a solution in $K$ it also has a solution in $K'$. So we can assume that $d_1, \ldots, d_m \in K'$, because elements of $I$ are determined entierely by non-$M$ part. This shows that $c_i$s are in $K'$. Adjoin every possible $c_i$s to the prime subfield of $K$, and denote it as $K_0$. Then $K_0 \subset K'$ for every field of definition $K'$. If we show that $K_0$ is a field of definition, we are done. The non-$M$ part of every element of $I$ is equal to the non-$M$ part of some linear combination of elements of form $\sum_i c_i m_i + m$. As before, since non-$M$ part determines the full element in $I$, this shows that $K_0$ is indeed a field of definition. Is this correct?